# Half of my lcd not showing data connected to arduino, Only showing White boxes Help plzz...Check pic in description

Tags: arduino

I have facing a problem while completing my Project. I have made a program for temperature sensor, in which I connected Lcd to show temperature, but problem is there, Lcd not showing data at whole, only half showing data, while half White boxes.

```
int tempPin=0;
int led1=5, led2=3;
float temp;
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 7, 6, 4, 2);
void setup() 
{
pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);      
pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);

 Serial.begin(9700);
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.println("< TEMP SENSOR >      ");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.println("    MADE BY:-    ");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(" Zubair Irfan");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(" Faizan Darwesh");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
 lcd.print(" M.Daniyal");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.clear();
  temp=analogRead(tempPin);
  temp=temp*0.48828125;
  lcd.print("     ");
   Serial.println(temp);

  delay(200);
Serial.println(temp);
  lcd.println(temp);

if(temp>=28)
{
digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
digitalWrite(led2,HIGH); 
delay(1000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.println("  D A N G E R  ");
}

else
{
digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2,LOW);

delay(1000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.println("  S A F E  ");
}
delay(2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code, or we won't be able to help.

Comment: int tempPin=0;
int led1=5, led2=3;
float temp;
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 7, 6, 4, 2);
void setup() 
{
pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);      
pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
 
 Serial.begin(9700);
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.println("< TEMP SENSOR >      ");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.println("    MADE BY:-    ");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(" Zubair Irfan");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(" Faizan Darwesh");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
 lcd.print(" M.Daniyal");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}

Comment: void loop()
{
  lcd.clear();
  temp=analogRead(tempPin);
  temp=temp*0.48828125;
  lcd.print("     ");
   Serial.println(temp);
   
  delay(200);
Serial.println(temp);
  lcd.println(temp);
  
if(temp>=28)
{
digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
digitalWrite(led2,HIGH); 
delay(1000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.println("  D A N G E R  ");
}

else
{
digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2,LOW);

delay(1000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.println("  S A F E  ");
}
delay(2000);
}

Comment: Please post your code by editing the queestion instead of as comments.

Comment: Did you try to move the contrast potentiometer?

Comment: nothing happening :(